# What are some good books for understanding the concept of limits for someone with an engineering background?

Tags: limits, book-recommendation

I have been trying to understand the concept of limits since I was in college. It's been 6 years, and I still cannot understand it. I am from the engineering side. I tried to read some advanced books, but they became very advanced very quickly. I am looking for a book that gradually explains things and is also in-depth. At this point, I am wondering whether there is some book present or not. If someone knows some books, please suggest them. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried Spivak’s Calculus?

Comment: I've made a video sometime back trying to show how epsilon delta definition connects with approximations we may do in real life [Shameless plug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68Dw_3pCOyo). But, inspid's suggestion is good. That book is really great.

Comment: If you do well with pictures, Pugh's real analysis book may be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend    Courant: Differential and integral calculus

Answer (score 0):

You may try out the book "A course in mathematical analysis: foundations and elementary real analysis (volume I)" from the author D. J. H. Garling. As an alternative, you can give a chance to "Analysis I" from Terence Tao. If you like the Russian way of teaching, "Mathematical Analysis I" from Vladimir Zorich is a good reference as well.

Comment: I like Garling's books, but I think his three volumes of mathematical analysis are more suitable for students majored in mathematics or statistics.